# what's the regex to identify a "string" + " string"?

Tags: regex

I'd like to identify two strings with a plus sign between them, but the plus sign can be with or without leading and/or trailing spaces...
examples:

```
tree + bowl
```

or

```
flower+sun
```

or

```
disk+ drive
```

or

```
large +database
```

any ideas?

Comment: What's the language or environment and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Optional spaces: `\s*`…?

Comment: No language env yet, just trying to test it on some regex test websites to find the right pattern to use. My challenge is the pattern, not the language specific implementation.

Comment: You'd better tag the end programming language. RegEx engines differ both in syntax and available features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`\w+ ?\+ ?\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/2hXfZz/1). It uses the [`?` quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) which makes matching the previous token optional.

If there could be more than one space, you could try [`\w+ *\+ *\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/2hXfZz/2), since `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times.